# How to handle get methods for user's profile in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, get

I will explain more here so that it's clear what I am trying to do. I am creating a web application using Express.js and Node.js. I am trying to create a user profile at this moment. I have seen different way to render the user profile some websites goes like : Quora : https://www.quora.com/profile/************, Stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/users/4056534/sandip-subedi and Facebook/Many other www.facebook.com/username.

I want to make something like what Facebook is doing. www.MYURL.com/USERNAME. How do I achieve that ? I know how to handle GET request and POST requests. There is a problem here because I already have more than 40 GET/POST request with different URL names. Since all of them are coming from www.MYURL.com/DOSOMETHING I couldn't figure out right way to filter if it is a user's profile or other URL. If I was doing something like www.MYURL.com/user/USERNAME it will be easy because I already know I am dealing with user at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a router to namespace endpoints:

```
let router = express.Router()
router.get("/:username", (req, res, next) => {
    // req.params will have the URL's username parameter
    console.log("Request for user with username", req.params.username)
})
app.use("/user", router)
```

This mounts the `username` route on the `user` route: `/user/[username]`

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: That might work when they click on some link on my website. What if they directly type www.MYURL.com/sandipsubedi on the web browser ? it will be router.get("/sandipsubedi") or something like that. What do I do on those instances ?

Comment: In your application you would have to interpret the user input somehow. Maybe you have some users stored in a database, as well as other kinds of data, say, communities. You could see if whatever the entered in the URL matched something in your data, then point them to the correct place. I won't speculate on implementation of that, as it could take many forms.